# is there a way of doing this without using global keyword or loops?

Tags: python, recursion

Passing l(so I can use it as a local variable inside the function) as arguement doesn't seem like a great way because it gets re-initialized everytime we call the function

```
l = s.split(' ')

ns = ''


def revur(s, i=0):
    global ns
    if i >= len(s):
        return ns
    ns = s[i] + ns
    return revur(s, i+1)


def wrur(s, i=0):
    global l, ns
    ns = ''
    l[i] = revur(l[i])
    if i >= len(l)-1:
        s = ' '.join(l)
        return s
    return wrur(s, i + 1)


print(wrur(s))
```

input: hi how are you
output: ih woh era uoy

Answer (score 1):

Using `map()`, slicing and `.join()`:

```
print(' '.join(map(lambda x: x[::-1],s.split())))
```

Where `s` is your string

Comment: Can you try without using inbuilt function also?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible to accomplish without *any* loops, because each character in the string needs to be affected, but there are multiple O(N) solutions, one being:

```
' '.join([word[::-1] for word in s.split()])
```

This solution, along with the the other answer, showcases the two main ways of changing each item in an iterable.

Comment: Can you try without using inbuilt function also?

Comment: @VishwasRVibhu It's possible to create `join()` and `split()` in code, but that's beyond the scope of this question. I would point you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053129/solving-split-string-in-python-without-the-use-of-split-function) for an example of `split()`.

Comment: It's not about making this happen without in built split. My main question is, we should be able to do this without using global keyword although we must use recursion. This is a logical constraint I've put on myself just to improve my logical thinking. I couldn't figure it out. Hence I have posted it here. Please tell me if you figure it out.